# Apache Web Server port 443 and Tomcat port 8080, redirect not working

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, tomcat, virtual-host

I have a Java web application on CentOS on Google Cloud. I can access my web app with `http://mydomain:8080`. I wish `https://mydomain` (without `8080` in URL) to lead to application, but instead, I just get the "123 test" Apache page. I know I need to do a proxy redirect, but I'm struggling with that. I need that port `443` redirects to Tomcat `8080`.

I've tried this inside tag `<VirtualHost>`:

1.

```
ProxyPass / http://www.mydomain.zone:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mydomain.zone:8080
```

2. 

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://www.mydomain.zone:8080"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://www.mydomain.zone:8080"
```

3. 

```
ProxyPass / https://www.mydomain.zone:8443
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.mydomain.zone:8443
```

4. 

```
ProxyPass "/" "https://www.mydomain.zone:8443"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://www.mydomain.zone:8443"
```

Also in config file, always above those tried lines, but inside Virtual Host tag I have:

```
 ProxyRequests On
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Proxy>
```

After each try, I would do this command: `systemctl restart httpd`

Also, I'm confused about which file I need to write these lines. There is `conf/httpd.conf` `conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf` and in different folder `conf.d/ssl.conf`.

Modules from `conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf`

```
# This file configures all the proxy modules:
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_fdpass_module modules/mod_proxy_fdpass.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

Tomcat's `server.xml`

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
        maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="/tmp/mydomain.zone.jks"
        keystorePass="pass"
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I wondered if there was any `iptables` rule that I implemented before, but it doesn't seem so, I deleted them. These are current active `iptables` rules:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_trusted
-N FWDI_trusted_allow
-N FWDI_trusted_deny
-N FWDI_trusted_log
-N FWDO_trusted
-N FWDO_trusted_allow
-N FWDO_trusted_deny
-N FWDO_trusted_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_trusted
-N IN_trusted_allow
-N IN_trusted_deny
-N IN_trusted_log
-N OUTPUT_direct
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i eth0 -g FWDI_trusted
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_trusted
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o eth0 -g FWDO_trusted
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_trusted
-A FWDI_trusted -j FWDI_trusted_log
-A FWDI_trusted -j FWDI_trusted_deny
-A FWDI_trusted -j FWDI_trusted_allow
-A FWDI_trusted -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_trusted -j FWDO_trusted_log
-A FWDO_trusted -j FWDO_trusted_deny
-A FWDO_trusted -j FWDO_trusted_allow
-A FWDO_trusted -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_ZONES -i eth0 -g IN_trusted
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_trusted
-A IN_trusted -j IN_trusted_log
-A IN_trusted -j IN_trusted_deny
-A IN_trusted -j IN_trusted_allow
-A IN_trusted -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: “I need that port `443` redirects to Tomcat `8080`.” Nope. You want port 443 to simply be a conduit to port 8080. Look at [this answer I posted on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/486112/100013) for more details. Also, be sure that the `VirtualHost` for the main site for port 80 and port 443 both respond correctly to the server’s host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 problems that occurred and the problem was not about proxy rules, I wrote them correctly.

I found the solution for the first problem here: http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/

Apparently, SELinux didn't allow httpd could not initiate outbound connections. I needed to allow it:  `/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

The second problem was that my Tomcat used too much RAM memory because I configure SSL in `server.xml`, but SSL is already enabled in my Apache. When I commented that out, Tomcat reduced his RAM consumption.